# multiple PowerShell variables come up blank when in a line of output

Tags: powershell

I have a VM maintenance script I'm working on and am trying to capture the output to a log.  I am looking to gather states of the VMs as the script progresses so I can do some fine tuning with my timed loops for checks/actions.

The issue I have is with my code below. The 1st and 2nd VM status variables in the Write-Output line always show as blanks in my output, but work fine when I put them separately.

```
$Server_1_1D = Get-VMGuest -VM 1st-VM
$Server_2_1D = Get-VMGuest -VM 2nd-VM
$Server_3_1D = Get-VMGuest -VM 3rd-VM
$Server_1_1D_Name = $Server_1_1D.VmName
$Server_2_1D_Name = $Server_2_1D.VmName
$Server_3_1D_Name = $Server_3_1D.VmName
$Server1_1D_Status = $Server_1_1D.State
$Server2_1D_Status = $Server_2_1D.State
$Server3_1D_Status = $Server_3_1D.State
$Server1_1D_Status
$Server2_1D_Status
$Server3_1D_Status
Write-Output "Initial check: $Server_1_1D_Name was $Server_1_1D_Status, $Server_2_1D_Name was $Server_2_1D_Status, and $Server_3_1D_Name was $Server3_1D_Status." 
$Server1_1D_Status
$Server2_1D_Status
```

The output of the above code.  In the Write-Output line the 1st-VM and 2nd-VM are both missing their status variable, but the 3rd-VM shows up consistently regardless of placement and number of them I've put in the Write-Output line:

```
PS C:\> C:\Scripted_Tasks\Issue.ps1
Running
Running
Running 
Initial check: 1st-VM was , 2nd-VM was , and 3rd-VM was Running
Running
Running
```

Any help or direction is most appreciated.

**UPDATE 2016/12/01: What Works**

Got rid of my variable names and started over without underscores.  Got some assist from a friend on the Write-Output with how to call the different properties to by using brackets.  Much cleaner.

Thanks for the replies.

```
$Server1 = Get-VMGuest -VM “Server1”
$Server2 = Get-VMGuest -VM “Server2”
$Server3 = Get-VMGuest –VM “Server3”
Write-Output "Initial check: $($Server1.VmName) was $($Server1.State), $($Server2.VmName) was $($Server2.State), and $($Server3.VmName) was $($Server3.State)."
```

PowerShell’s Output is now:

```
Initial check: Server1 was Running, Server2 was Running, and Server3 was Running.
```

Comment: `$server1_` in your variable name vs `$server_1_` in your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that where you are defining your variable you have:

> $Server1_, $Server2_, $Server3_

When you call the variable to output it, you are calling:

> $Server_1_, $Server_2_, $Server_3_

Adding in an extra _ before the numbers.

Effectively you are calling an entirely different variable that has not been defined.

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  I got some further help from a friend who gave me a cleaner write-output by doing $($Server1.property) for the name and state.